# Understanding type family

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
type family Times (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat) :: Nat where 
   Times Z n = Z
   Times (S m) n = Plus n (Times m n)
```

I know that type families allow you to write functions on the type level. However, for the code above, I know that `(a :: Nat) (b :: Nat)` are the types of the two parameters that are passed to the function `Times`.

However I don't understand what the final `:: Nat` after `(a :: Nat) (b :: Nat)` means. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Would it be clearer if it was written `type family Times :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat where (...)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The final `:: Nat` indicates that the type-level function returns a `Nat`.

Comment: I didn’t know the family types, thanks for sharing!